# Unable to sudo as newly created user in OS X, error: sudo: 4294967295,701,100: invalid value

Tags: macos, sudo

Unable to sudo as newly created user under OS X Catalina.

Created a new user:

```
sudo su
<enter password>
dscl . -create /Users/testuser1
dscl . -create /Users/testuser1 UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/testuser1 RealName "Testuser1"
dscl . -create /Users/testuser1 NFSHomeDirectory /opt/testuser1
dscl . -create /Users/testuser1 UniqueID 517
dscl . -create /Users/testuser1 PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -passwd /Users/testuser1 testuser1pwd
```

User appears to be created.

```
sudo -u testuser1 cat test.txt
```

Output:

```
sudo: 4294967295,701,100: invalid value
```

I am obviously missing something, but my google fu fails me.